# Printing variable subscripts in Julia

Tags: julia

Hey so I know that due to the Unicode support in Julia one, may write for instance the letter a with the subscript 1 by typing `a\_1<TAB>`. Now, what if I wanted to do something like the following:

```
for i in [1 2 3]
    println("a\_i")
end
```

and have the output be written as

```
a₁
a₂
a₃
```

How would I go about this without writing out all the possible subscripts myself?

Comment: The unicode characters you want are `\u208X`. If you iterate `for i in "\u2081\u2082\u2083"` you can get what you want, but I don't think there's a built-in way to convert from number to unicode subscript.

Comment: You can write a string macro for this. [LaTeXStrings.jl](https://github.com/stevengj/LaTeXStrings.jl) is close but not exactly what you want.

Comment: Writing a custom converter should be pretty simple `subscript(i::Integer) = i<0 ? error("$i is negative") : string(('₀'+d for d in digits(i))...)`

Comment: or with a simpler body: `join('₀'+d for d in digits(i))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this (at least in version 0.6):

```
ltx = Base.REPLCompletions.latex_symbols

for i in 1:3 
    println("a$(ltx["\\_$i"])") 
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Bogumił Kamiński's answer seems the neatest, but I needed to reverse the order to get the correct string for two-digit numbers:

```
subscript(i::Integer) = i<0 ? error("$i is negative") : join('₀'+d for d in reverse(digits(i)))

for i=7:13 println("a"*subscript(i)) end
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off the other answers here, I wrote a set of functions to allow for negative numbers and to work with the more complex superscript case.

```
function subscriptnumber(i::Int)
    if i < 0
        c = [Char(0x208B)]
    else
        c = []
    end
    for d in reverse(digits(abs(i)))
        push!(c, Char(0x2080+d))
    end
    return join(c)
end

function superscriptnumber(i::Int)
    if i < 0
        c = [Char(0x207B)]
    else
        c = []
    end
    for d in reverse(digits(abs(i)))
        if d == 0 push!(c, Char(0x2070)) end
        if d == 1 push!(c, Char(0x00B9)) end
        if d == 2 push!(c, Char(0x00B2)) end
        if d == 3 push!(c, Char(0x00B3)) end
        if d > 3 push!(c, Char(0x2070+d)) end
    end
    return join(c)
end
```

```
julia> for i in [1 -2 39]
           println("a"*superscriptnumber(i))
           println("a"*subscriptnumber(i))
       end
a¹
a₁
a⁻²
a₋₂
a³⁹
a₃₉
```